# Restfull Webservice Maven Project netbeans

Tags: java, rest, maven, netbeans, jax-rs

I'm looking at every way to try to make a request type to get to my web service created by restfull Webservice into a project with Tomcat , Maven and some servlets , but nothing I do not start by mistake does not find the resource . What am I doing wrong? I may not have configured the web.xml ? how can I do?
I put the file pom.xml below and

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20150729</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is code of my web service:

```
@Path("ws")
public class WsUserJson {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of WsUserJson
     */
    public WsUserJson() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of com.lillonet.testmavenservletws.WsUserJson
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getJson(@QueryParam("name") String nome) {

        //TODO return proper representation object
        return "{"+nome+"}";
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of WsUserJson
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void putJson(String content) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That is only a jar with a bunch of interfaces. There is no implementation. That dependency should only be used when you plan on deploying to a an EE compliant Server, like Glassfish or Wildfly. Tomcat is not an EE compliant server. It is only a Servlet container. Therefore any features you use from that `javaee-web-api`, you need to also include an *implementation*.

So for now, just get rid of it so you don't use ant classes for which there is no implementation. Then you need to decide on a JAX-RS implementation to use. For now I'll just say to use Jersey. So just add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you need to configure the application in the web.xml. You can see [here for more options](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet). You basically want something like

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.foo.myresources</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The `param-value` in the `init-param` is the package you want Jersey to scan to pick up and register all your classes annotated with `@Path` and `@Provider`. The scan is recursive, so you can list the root-most package in your project if you have your resource scattered in different packages.

From here it should work. Then for JSON/POJO support, you can just add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

No extra configuration is needed for that.